# Spring Boot Kafka Streams - Binding Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying build out a simple streams app based on Kafka Streams using this example.

[Word Count](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-word-count)

However when I am starting the app, I get the below error: Can someone please point out on what I am missing out here? Here is the code, config & error

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@EnableScheduling
@EnableBinding(PersonBinding.class)
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Component
  public static class PersonSource {

    private final MessageChannel personOut;

    @Autowired
    PersonSource(PersonBinding personBinding) {

      this.personOut = personBinding.personOut();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000L)
    public void run() {

      Message<Person> message = MessageBuilder
          .withPayload(new Person("John", "Doe", Instant.now()))
          .build();

      try {

        personOut.send(message);

        log.info("Published message: {}", message);
      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
      }
    }
  }

  @Component
  public static class PersonProcessor {

    @StreamListener
    public void process(@Input(PersonBinding.PERSON_IN) KStream<String, Person> events) {

      events.foreach(((key, value) -> System.out.println("Key: " + key + "; Value: " + value)));
    }
  }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Person {

  String firstName;

  String lastName;

  Instant createdOn;
}

interface PersonBinding {

  String PERSON_IN = "pin";

  String PERSON_OUT = "pout";

  @Output(PERSON_OUT)
  MessageChannel personOut();

  @Input(PERSON_IN)
  KStream<String, Person> personIn();
}
```

Dependency Management (Spring Boot 1.5.13.RELEASE)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kstream</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Configuration

```
# Default Configuration
spring.cloud.stream.kstream.binder.configuration.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kstream.binder.configuration.default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
# Out Bindings Configuration
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pout.destination=pout
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pout.producer.header-mode=raw
# In Bindings Configuration
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pin.destination=pout
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pin.consumer.header-mode=raw
```

Error

```
Field configurationProperties in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.config.KafkaBinderConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
  - spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder-org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.properties.KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties: a programmatically registered singleton - binderConfigurationProperties: defined by method 'binderConfigurationProperties' in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kstream/config/KStreamBinderSupportAutoConfiguration.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

** EDIT 1 **

Uploaded code to Github
https://github.com/tapitoe/demo-spring-cloud-streams/tree/master/src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the kstream binder to the pom; the starter only adds the message channel binder.

**EDIT**

I just copied similar code into an app with no problems.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(So50693858Application.PersonBinding.class)
public class So50693858Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So50693858Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener
    public void process(@Input(PersonBinding.PERSON_IN) KStream<String, String> events) {

        events.foreach(((key, value) -> System.out.println("Key: " + key + "; Value: " + value)));
    }

    interface PersonBinding {

        String PERSON_IN = "pin";

        String PERSON_OUT = "pout";

        @Output(PERSON_OUT)
        MessageChannel personOut();

        @Input(PERSON_IN)
        KStream<String, String> personIn();
    }

}
```

and sent a message from the console producer to `pout` and

```
Key: null; Value: foo
```

It's not clear, however, why you have input and output bindings to the same destination (not that that would cause the problem you see).

**EDIT**

This works too (with your properties):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(So50693858Application.PersonBinding.class)
public class So50693858Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So50693858Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel pout) {
        return args -> {
            pout.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo".getBytes(),
                    Collections.singletonMap(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "bar".getBytes())));
            pout.send(new GenericMessage<>("baz".getBytes(),
                    Collections.singletonMap(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "qux".getBytes())));
        };
    }

    @StreamListener
    public void process(@Input(PersonBinding.PERSON_IN) KStream<String, String> events) {

        events.foreach(((key, value) -> System.out.println("Key: " + key + "; Value: " + value)));
    }

    interface PersonBinding {

        String PERSON_IN = "pin";

        String PERSON_OUT = "pout";

        @Output(PERSON_OUT)
        MessageChannel personOut();

        @Input(PERSON_IN)
        KStream<String, String> personIn();
    }

}
```

and

```
Key: bar; Value: foo
Key: qux; Value: baz
```

**EDIT3**

Pom for 2.0.x version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so50693858</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>so50693858</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

config:

```
# Default Configuration
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
# Out Bindings Configuration
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pout.destination=pout
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pout.producer.header-mode=raw
# In Bindings Configuration
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pin.destination=pout
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pin.consumer.header-mode=raw
```

Comment: Added the binder dependency. Still having the same issue.

Comment: If you're still seeing `registered factories: channelFactory` in the exception; the jar does not appear to be on the class path.

Comment: You added the kafka binder (which is already there via the starter); you need the kstreams binder.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue Gary. Now I get an error informing that there are 2 beans found for configurationProperties in KafkaBinderConfiguration. When/how should I use the default and when I need to, how do I make mine @Primary?

Comment: What do you mean by "mine" ? I just copied your code and had no problems - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: I have created a git repo with the code.
https://github.com/tapitoe/demo-spring-cloud-streams

Comment: I tried running the code in your sample and I am still getting the same error complaining about 2 beans of the type KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties in KafkaBinderConfiguration. I have uploaded my code to the GitHub Repo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172533/discussion-between-tapitoe-and-gary-russell).

Comment: Can you upgrade to boot 2.0.2 and cloud Finchley,RC2? That's what I was testing with. I get the problem with your project (not sure why) but it's using boot 1.5 and cloud Edgware.

Comment: I tried to upgrade to 2.x and Finchley and Edgware and both resulted in compile time and runtime issues respectively. Eventually I would like to get it working with 1.5.x version with Edgware GA versions. Maybe I am not using the right dependencies but I noticed that even trying to replicate https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPDzcmqwCNo&t=1128s isn't working.

Comment: Turns out it was a [known problem](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/pull/315); you would need to open a GitHub issue if you want the fix back-ported - any particular reason you can't move to more recent technology? Ditmars is nearly a year old;

Comment: Thanks for confirming Gary. Btw, do you know what I am missing with the dependencies when upgrading to 2.x and Edgware? I would like to try and get it working with a GA version before pursuing convincing the team to move to 2.x.

Comment: You need Finchley - see my POM. Note: The stream components are all GA (2.0.0) pulled in by the Finchley RC2 BOM which pulls in Elmhurst.RELEASE. You shouldn't see any non-GA jars; if you don't want to use the RC2 BOM, you can pull in the Elmhurst.RELEASE deps directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gary. I am now able to get the demo app working with 2.x and Finchley. I will try to see if we can move to 2.x else, I will open a Github issue to get the fix retrofitted to 1.5.x.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, It got fixed after I added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `EnableBinding` annotation to `DemoApplication` class. I believe it should be put on `@Configuration` class, not on arbitrary `@Component`.

Comment: Updated the code and moved @EnableBinding to DemoApplication class level. Still having the same issue.